# Oracle's plain behavior on EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with REPLACE and variable bind

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to avoid oracle's plain to be calculated at every dynamic SQL use.

Using `REPLACE` and then a `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` without `USING` leads to overhead, as the string is different at every use, Oracle always seems to search a new plain.

But reading about `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement a found the following:

[You can execute a dynamic SQL statement repeatedly using new values for the bind arguments. You still incur some overhead, because EXECUTE IMMEDIATE re-prepares the dynamic string before every execution.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)

Is that? Does `USING` bind forces Oracle to recalculate every dynamic string? If so, how to avoid it?

```
a) querytoselect = REPLACE( querytoselect, 'pattern', 'var' );
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE querytoselect.

b) EXECUTE IMMEDIATE querytoselect USING var
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your example code and SQL statements.

Comment: a) implies on another plain, does b)?

Comment: If you are using bind variables, and the SQL statement to execute is the same, then I would think oracle would not do a hard parse again.  Try a test and look at the V$sqlarea view to see what shows up.

Comment: The text on oracle's doc site raised the doubt.
I'll search about V$sqlarea, I have some years of C++ but 0,5 of Oracle \m/

Comment: Do you use TOAD by any chance?  It has a nice SGA viewer.

Comment: I use another software. Usually Oracle's SQL Dev.

Comment: This [thread on Tom Kyte's site](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2588723819082) is kind of long but it deserves to be read.

Comment: Long? Did you mean huge? =D

227 pages when pasted into libreoffice

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin and starts with the question "Can you explain BRIEFLY the difference... don't wanna see the normal explain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` always does a parse, but if the statement is identical to one already in memory, it can simply use the plan already determined (this is called a "soft parse") instead of having to fully parse the statement and determine a new plan (a "hard parse").

There is really more subtlety to it than that, and depends on your configuration as well.  For instance, even if a matching statement is found in memory, bind peeking and table statistics could result in a hard parse being performed to determine if there is a potentially better plan given the particular input.

But overall, a soft parse is less overhead than a hard parse, and using bind variables increases the chance of avoiding a hard parse.

To completely avoid re-parsing, you can use `DBMS_SQL` instead of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and hold onto the cursor after parsing.  I wouldn't bother doing this unless you've identified a significant performance issue caused by soft parsing.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel Don't know the current situation in 11g and 12c versions, but in 9i and 10g DBMS_SQL was slower then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and it was stated in documentation. If I correctly remember the difference was 1.5 - 3 times according to Oracle.

Comment: Ok, I'll search for it.